# How to keep TYPO3's RTE from adding an empty line before <ul>s

Tags: editor, typo3, rte, typo3-6.1.x, typo3-4.5

In TYPO3 4.5 as well as 6.1, whenever I add an unordered list element, RTEhtmlarera (or some of its many processing routines) will add an extra

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

before the ul tag on saving the content element.

[image]

This happens only once, when the ul is inserted first. When the p tag is removed and the content element is saved again, it won't happen again.

How can this erroneous behaviour be removed?

Answer (score 2):

Hi try set `encapsLines` to zero..

Setup typoscript:

```
tt_content.stdWrap.dataWrap > 
lib.parseFunc_RTE.nonTypoTagStdWrap.encapsLines >
```

Comment: I've tried that, but couldn't see the desired effect. I'm not sure if it should, though, as my issue occurs in the backend already, so I thought the parseFunc wouldn't apply, as this is a frontend thing?

Comment: This just works fine for me: `lib.parseFunc_RTE.nonTypoTagStdWrap.encapsLines.remapTag.DIV >`

Comment: `lib.parseFunc_RTE.nonTypoTagStdWrap.encapsLines >` works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Not a real solution but maybe a hint in the right direction.
If you write down your list, do not press enter before the first list entry but shift+enter.
Example:

```
Here comes the list: <<-- AT THIS POINT PRESS SHIFT+ENTER
- a <<-- Here it does not matter if you press enter or shift+enter
- b
- c
- ...
```

This works for me as a workaround. I've done a lot of research in sysext:rtehtmlarea but nothing worked. So this looks for me like some kind of mysterious bug/feature connected with the "BR to P" (or vice versa) configuration you can define in pageTS or Setup. BTW: I never fully understood this conversion-thing :)

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure I can teach this to editors. Do you think it's a bug in RTE? Have you seen a related issue on the forge? And most of all: What happens if you disable "BR to P"? Is that thing gone then?

Answer (score 0):

For me with 6.1 this worked:

```
lib.parseFunc_RTE {
    externalBlocks = table, blockquote, ol, ul, div, dl, address, hr
    externalBlocks {
        ol.stripNL=1
        ol.stdWrap.parseFunc = < lib.parseFunc

        ul.stripNL=1
        ul.stdWrap.parseFunc = < lib.parseFunc

        # i have also seen this setting, but didn´t test it:
        # blockquote.stripNLprev = 1 
        # blockquote.stripNLnext = 1
    }
}
```

I removed many lines for this example, be aware that you overwrite previous settings by using {} ..

Comment: Actually, my issue occurs in the backend already, not only in the frontend - yours?